# What's the meaning of '_' in python?

Tags: python, django, syntax

When reading source code of Django, I find some statements:

```
class Field(object):  
    """Base class for all field types"""  
    __metaclass__ = LegacyConnection  

    # Generic field type description, usually overriden by subclasses
    def _description(self):
        return _(u'Field of type: %(field_type)s') % {
            'field_type': self.__class__.__name__
        }    
    description = property(_description) 

class AutoField(Field):
    description = _("Integer")
```

I know it set description as 'Integer', but don't understand the syntax: `description = _("Integer")`.
Can some one help on it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [\_ as variable name in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739514/as-variable-name-in-python)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Please read up on Internationalization (i18n)

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

The `_` is a commonly-used name for the function that translates strings to another language.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation

Also, read all of these related questions on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdjango%5D+i18n

Answer (score 13):

Not an answer to your case but the more general "What's the meaning of '_' in python?":

In *interactive mode*, a `_` will return the last result that wasn't assigned to a variable

```
>>> 1 # _ = 1
1
>>> _ # _ = _
1
>>> a = 2
>>> _
1
>>> a # _ = a
2
>>> _ # _ = _
2
>>> list((3,)) # _ = list((3,))
[3]
>>> _ # _ = _
[3]
```

Not sure, but it seems like every expression that's not assigned to a variable is actually assigned to `_`.

Comment: It seems there is another usage of '_' in python program.  
Such as:
I_need, _, I_need_2 = ('a', 'b', 'c');
in this case, you don't care about the second value in the tuple, so it saves your time to think up some variable names for these useless values which makes the code easier to read.

Comment: @Beyonder: True, but in that instance it's acting like any other variable, just using the most forgettable name possible `_` to say "I'm a throwaway variable".

Comment: it is the Matlab's equivalent of "ans"?

Comment: @David interactively, yes.

Answer (score 6):

this is used for gettext function, as is described [here](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#gettext.gettext)

Utf-8 support of  django is good, so django handles it as unicodetext as described [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#standard-translation)

Answer (score 0):

_ indicates last valid output on the screen. System by default stores copy of the output to this _ variable. It does not applies to string that is printed using print function but I stores for the string stored into the variable.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cimq7.png)