# what do _ and __ mean in PYTHON

Tags: python

When I input `_` or `__` in the python shell I get values returned. For instance:

```
>>> _
2
>>>__
8
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Are you using a "normal" Python shell?

Comment: @BartoszKP: I didn't add thank you, it was in original post. i corrected the spelling, that's all.

Comment: For `_`, you may have look at this answer [_ in  python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3969587/2438678)

Comment: @BartoszKP he didn't add anything in the edit. He corrected a word misspelling.

Comment: @Payeli Right, sorry, I've misread it. Anyway - you should've remove it then :)

Comment: when i input `__name__`, i got `'__main__'`.And I think it's global variables.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using IPython then the following GLOBAL variables always exist:

- `_` *(a single underscore)*: stores previous output, like Python’s default interpreter.
- `__` *(two underscores)*: next previous.
- `___` *(three underscores)*: next-next previous.

Read more about it from IPython documentation: [Output caching system](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#output-caching-system).

Comment: Do you know where it's defined in python. I don't found the path and the file name.

Answer (score 6):

Theoretically these are just ordinary variable names. By convention, a single underscore is used as a *don't care* variable. For example, if a function returns a tuple, and you're interested only in one element, a Pythonic way to ignore the other is:

```
_, x = fun()
```

In some interpreters `_` and `__` have special meanings, and store values of previous evaluations.

Comment: Worth noting that this is not only (or originally) "pythonic". In some languages which do not allow destructive assignment, `_` is the only variable which can be reassigned, but can never be read.

Comment: The "don't care" variables are often referred to as *holes*.

Answer (score 3):

In Python it means what you tell it to mean. Underscores are valid characters in a name. (However, if you are using IPython see [Martin's fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20906785/418413).)

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> _
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '_' is not defined
>>> _=2
>>> _
2
>>> __
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__' is not defined
>>> __=3
>>> __
3
```

That said, they do have some special semantics. Starting a name with a single underscore doesn't do anything programmatically different, but by convention it tells you the name is intended to be private. But if you start a name with two underscores the interpreter will obfuscate it.

```
>>> class Bar:
...   _=2
...   __=3
...   _x=2
...   __x=3
... 
>>> y=Bar()
>>> y._
2
>>> y.__
3
>>> y._x
2
>>> y.__x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Bar instance has no attribute '__x'
>>> dir(y)
['_', '_Bar__x', '__', '__doc__', '__module__', '_x']
>>> y._Bar__x
3
```

Comment: 3x! Where can i find more knowledge related to this, official doc ?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#output-caching-system), in iPython:

- `_` (a single underscore): stores previous output, like Python’s
  default interpreter.
- `__` (two underscores): next previous output.

You can also reference previous inputs and outputs depending on the line they are by:

**Input:** `_iX` where `X` is the input line number

**Ouput:** `_X` where `X` is the output line number

**Examples:**

**`_`**

```
In [1]: 9 * 3
Out[1]: 27

In [2]: _ 
Out[2]: 27
```

**`__`**

```
In [1]: 9 * 3
Out[1]: 27

In [2]: 4 * 8
Out[2]: 32

In [3]: __
Out[3]: 27
```

**`_iX`**

```
In [1]: x = 10

In [2]: y = 5

In [3]: _i1
Out[3]: u'x = 10'
```

**`_X`**

```
In [1]: x = 10

In [2]: y = 4

In [3]: x + y
Out[3]: 14

In [4]: _3
Out[4]: 14
```