# Why django uses tuple of tuples to store static dictionaries and should i do the same?

Tags: python, django, performance, dictionary, tuples

Why django uses tuple of tuples to store for example `choices` instead of standard dict?

Example:

```
ORGINAL_MARKET = 1
SECONDARY_MARKET = 2
MARKET_CHOICES = (
     (ORGINAL_MARKET, _('Orginal Market')),
     (SECONDARY_MARKET, _('Secondary Market')),
 )
```

And should I do it to when I know the dict won't change in time?
I reckon the tuples are faster but does it matter if when I try to get value I'm still need to convert it to dict to find it?

UPDATE:

Clarification if I use it as a tuple of tuples I will be getting value using

```
dict(self.MARKET_CHOICES)[self.ORGINAL_MARKET]
```

Which will work faster, this or storing values in dict from the beginning?

Comment: Could you provide link to Django using this method? What is the underscore?

Comment: Not only that (tuples being leaner/faster), but tuple also preserve order while dict don't (if you want to preserve order there is collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: @JanVlcinsky: the underscore is an alias for the translation function from GNU gettext library (internationalization/localization stuff).

Comment: underscore is shorthand for internationalization (not relevant) details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3967260/1016772

Example from in django docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#choices

Comment: The "static" word in the question is the key here. Since there are no static dicts, tuples probably are the simplest option to store key/value pairs if you need a static structure.

Comment: To be clear: I'm not going to use it in `choices=`- I'm looking for most efficient method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuples are immutable, slightly faster, and Django uses them because they're immutable in the `choices` parameter in fields.

If you're using Python 3.4 or later you can use [`Enums`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) also which is better than both tuples and dictionaries (but I'm not sure if Django supports them for the `choices` parameter).

Comment: For now I'm using 2.7. Maybe if I will have some free work time I will migrate it to newest django and python 3 (free work time = not going to happen)

Comment: `Enums` are backported to Python 2.7 and available via `$ pip install enum34`. Functionality is exactly the same. Do not confuse with `enum` package on pypi, which is similar but a bit different.

Answer (score 6):

The main reason is that ordering is preserved.  If you used a dictionary, and called `.items()` on it to give the choices for a `ChoiceField`, for example, the ordering of items in the select box would be unreliable when you rendered the form.

If you want the dict, it is easy to create one from the tuple of tuples, the format is already one accepted by the constructer so you can just call `dict()` on it.

I don't think the immutability is a correct reason - it is not strictly necessary for them to be a tuple of tuples, a list of tuples or even a list of lists would work as well in Django.

Comment: Since this question was asked, python dictionaries now preserve their order

Answer (score 0):

> To be clear: I'm not going to use it in choices=- I'm looking for most efficient method –  Lord_JABA

If you want your choices to have a particular order (which often is the case with the `choices` parameter) then use tuples, if you don't care use whatever literal you find easier to type (from the allowed datatypes), I doubt you will see any significant difference regarding the memory/cpu footprint for this specific use case.