# Dictionary comprehension with conditional

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary-comprehension

So I'm wondering if anyone can help me out with this issue I'm having.

Lets assume I have a dictionary:

```
d = {1: {2: 3}, 4: 5}
```

I want to create a dictionary of any contained dictionaries:

```
wanted_result = {2: 3}
```

what I am trying is this:

```
e = {inner_key: d[key][inner_key] for key in d.keys() for inner_key in d[key].keys() if isinstance(d[key], dict)}
```

However this is causing me to get an error saying that ints don't have keys, which I know, but I thought my conditional would exclude say 4 from my example from being included in the comprehension.

Comment: What should the result be if there is more than one nested dict? What if they are nested more deeply?

Comment: say started at d = {1: {2: {3: 4}, 5: 6}, 7: 8}, would just assume to get {2: {3: 4}, 5: 6} . ie only gathering the dictionaries one layer deep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first idea was something like this:

```
d = {1: {2: 3}, 4: 5, 6: {7: 8}}
generator = (x.items() for x in d.itervalues() if type(x) == dict)
s = dict(sum( generator, list() )) 
# s = {2: 3, 7: 8}
```

But, in order to avoid letting  `sum()` construct a large temporary list of all the `items()` you may use [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and `iteritems()` instead:

```
# chain "concatenates" iterables
from itertools import chain
d = {1: {2: 3}, 4: 5, 6: {7: 8}}
s = dict(chain( *(x.iteritems() for x in d.itervalues() if type(x) == dict) ))
# s = {2: 3, 7: 8}
```

You should be aware of edge cases. Especially if identical keys are in the part-dictionaries these will necessarily collapse somehow.

---

If you also want to support subclasses of `dict` to be collected from your `d.values()`, you may indeed want to use `isinstance` instead of `type`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549801/1025391) for details.

Comment: Why in earth did you choose `_` as your variable name? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1739541/972208)

Comment: @julio.alegria I used this occasionally for temporary variables (be sure to not shadow another `x`). Wasn't aware of the special semantics in interactive mode though!

Answer (score 10):

```
d = {1: {2: 3}, 4: 5, 6: {7: 8}}
s = {k: v for elem in d.values() if type(elem) is dict for k, v in elem.items()}
>> {2: 3, 7: 8}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I would recommend you a for-loop and the [`update`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method:

```
d = {1: {2: 3}, 4: 5, 6: {7: 8}}
inner_dicts = {}
for val in d.values():
    if type(val) is dict:
        inner_dicts.update(val)
print inner_dicts
# {2: 3, 7: 8}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following list comprehension will return each value that is a dict:

```
>>> d = {1: {2: 3}, 4: 5}
>>> [d[i] for i in d.keys() if isinstance(d[i],dict)]
[{2: 3}]
```

Comment: use `isinstance()`, it's much more pythonic.

Comment: didn't he explicitly asked for a "**dictionary** of any contained dictionaries"?

Comment: Obviously that is what he asked for, I'm just wondering how he would use that for multiple keys that are dicts.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {1: {2: 3}, 4: 5,'j':{7:8}}
e={y:d[x][y] for x in d if isinstance(d[x],dict) for y in d[x]}
print(e)

{2: 3, 7: 8}
```

Comment: didn't he explicitly asked for a "**dictionary** of any contained dictionaries"?

Answer (score 0):

Other way using lambda

`(lambda x: {k:v for x in d.values() if type(x) == dict for k,v in x.items()})(d)`