# Python solving 2nd order ODE with quad function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I am studying the dynamics of a damped, driven pendulum with second order ODE defined like [so](http://www.cmp.caltech.edu/%7Emcc/Chaos_Course/Lesson2/Demos.html), and specifically I am progamming:

```
d^2y/dt^2 + c * dy/dt + sin(y) = a * cos(wt)
```

...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate


def pendeq(t,y,a,c,w):
    y0 = -c*y[1] - np.sin(y[0]) + a*np.cos(w*t)
    y1 = y[1]
    z = np.array([y0, y1])
    return z

a = 2.1
c = 1e-4
w = 0.666667     # driving angular frequency

t = np.array([0, 5000])   # interval of integration
y = np.array([0, 0])      # initial conditions

yp = integrate.quad(pendeq, t[0], t[1], args=(y,a,c,w))
```

This problem does look quite similar to [Need help solving a second order non-linear ODE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779217/need-help-solving-a-second-order-non-linear-ode-in-python), but I am getting the error

```
Supplied function does not return a valid float.
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: It looks like you're solving for the position of the pendulum as a function of several parameters, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: `quad` integrates a scalar function.  It does not solve an ordinary differential equation.  Look again at the example you linked to--`scipy.integrate.odeint` (not `quad`) is used to generate the solution.  See also http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/CoupledSpringMassSystem

Answer (score 3):

`integrate.quad` requires that the function supplied (`pendeq`, in your case) **returns only a float**.  Your function is returning an array.

Comment: I've answered the part of the question "What am I doing wrong?", but I'm still trying to figure out how to do it right.  I'll edit my answer if I can figure it out.  At this point it's more of a physics problem than a programming problem.