# Is local variable necessary in Python comprehensions?

Tags: python, warnings, list-comprehension

In Python 3.x, I'm calling a function `rand_foo()` which returns some random stuff each time being called. I wish to store the sequence of random results into a list. I'm using the following construct:

```
r = [ rand_foo() for i in range(10) ]
```

Now my PyCharm 3.0 IDE keeps warning: `Local variable 'i' value is not used`.

Is there an elegant way of removing the unnecessary variable? Indeed, in some cases, I could use `itertools.repeat()` or something like `10*[value]`, which, however, cannot be applied to my example above.

Comment: I'd consider it to be a bug in PyCharm. It's very common for this type of expression to occur in Python code, and you shouldn't have to jump through hoops to avoid a silly warning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The convention when a variable is unused is to use an underscore instead:

```
r = [rand_foo() for _ in range(10)]
```

See for example: [Underscore _ as variable name in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739514/underscore-as-variable-name-in-python)

I believe this will suppress your PyCharm warning

Comment: +1, but one warning: There are a few libraries, most notably the [`gettext`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html) i18n module in the stdlib, that provide a special meaning for `_`, and if you use one of those, your linter (or a human reader) may complain that you're shadowing the global `_` with a local of the same name… (And, of course, if your expression is actually trying to _use_ `gettext`, you can't do this.)

Comment: What a *terrible* choice that was!

Comment: The Python `gettext` module is a wrapper around the C/Unix `gettext` library, which has been a de facto standard since the early 90s, and uses `_("string to localize")` to signal that the string should be localized. And perl, sh, Smalltalk, etc. bindings for `gettext` had already adopted the same `_` syntax. So there was really no choice…

Comment: Correct, the warning disappeared! Thanks.

Comment: Then, how to deal with the double loop? Something like `r=[[rand() for i in range(10)] for j in range(20)]` ?

Comment: @wsysuper if you don't care about the variable, you can actually reuse the underscore for both of them: `r=[[rand() for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(20)]`