# What does this line of code do when initializing a hash table in python?

Tags: python, arrays, hashtable

I'm looking at the solution for how to create a hash table in python and came across this function:

```
def __init__(self, size):
    self.size = size
    self.table = [[] for _ in range(self.size)]
```

The third line of code creating the multi-dimensional array is confusing me.  Mainly this part:

```
for _ in range(self.size)
```

What exactly is this doing?  And why is it needed instead of just doing something like this:

```
[[] self.size]
```

Which would create a 2-dimensional array with the size of self.size correct?  Any sort of visual aids would really help too.

Comment: `[[] self.size]` creates an array whose first element is an empty array, and second element is a number.

Comment: Did you mean `[] * self.size`?

Comment: for the underscore part, see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739514/underscore-as-variable-name-in-python

Comment: `[[] self.size]` is a syntax error. `[[], self.size]` would be a list containing an empty list and whatever `self.size` is.

Comment: Okay I was mistaken thinking that `[[] self.size]` was declaring an array of `self.size` size with each index containing an empty array.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @chadb768 there is no variable declaration in Python. And that isn't an array, that is a list. In fact, it is really a `SyntaxError`, so it's not even that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> good_table = [[] for _ in range(5)]
>>> good_table
[[], [], [], [], []]
>>> good_table[0].append(3)
>>> good_table
[[3], [], [], [], []]
>>> suggested_table = [[] 5]
  File "<input>", line 1
    suggested_table = [[] 5]
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> suggested_table = [[] * 5]
>>> suggested_table
[[]]
>>> [] * 5
[]
>>> bad_table = [[]] * 5
>>> bad_table
[[], [], [], [], []]
>>> bad_table[0].append(3)
>>> bad_table
[[3], [3], [3], [3], [3]]
```

For the last part, see [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly).

Comment: I would love to know why people are downvoting this. What information do I need to add? What hasn't already been thoroughly covered elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
self.table = [[] for _ in range(self.size)]
```

creates an array of buckets for holding the contents of the hash table.

The variable name `_` is used to indicate that the variable doesn't matter and its contents are, essentially, thrown away. This is useful for unused variables with a short scope, like this one.

You suggest initializing things like this:

```
self.table = [[]]*self.size
```

But this is a **bad idea** because you actually get `self.size` copies of the same list! That is:

```
a=[[]]*4
>>> [[], [], [], []]
a[0].append(3)
>>> [[3], [3], [3], [3]]
```

Comment: Of the same *list*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Quite right. I've fixed the mistake.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for coming off as pedantic, but it's a pet peeve of mine. Python lists are different than arrays, especially arrays in languages like C++ and Java. They are heterogeneous, resizable array-lists with constant-time append/extend operations.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: It was fuzzy wording on my part, and I appreciate the reminder that these are inherently different data structures.