# Something about the sys.getrefcount

Tags: python, garbage-collection, python-internals, reference-counting

After I ran "a.method",why the sys.getrefcount(a) returned 3? there was no new variable referred the object

```
class A(object):
   def method(): pass 

import sys
a=A()

sys.getrefcount(a) # returns 2

a.method
<bound method A.method of <__main__.A object at 0x7f1e73059b50>>

sys.getrefcount(a) # returns 3
```

Comment: please learn how to create a How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example before posting a question( https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve )

Comment: Are you using IPython or some other IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the python interactive shell, the result of the last command is stored in [a special varialbe named `_`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1739514/2096752).  Naturally, this variable holds a reference to that result.

In your case, the result is a method object, which holds a ref to its "self", i.e. the variable `a`.  In other words, in the case you describe, the extra ref is indirect. The result (`<bound method A.method of <__main__.A object at 0x7f1e73059b50>>`) which is kept alive due to variable `_`, holds a reference to `<__main__.A object at 0x7f1e73059b50>`.

Comment: The fun thing is that when you call `sys.getrefcount(a)` _again_, then it returns 2 because of what this answer describes (`_` is the integer `3` after the first `sys.getrefcount(a)`).